# What English sentences are represented by following expressions?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Let S = Steve is happy, G = George is happy

$1. (S \lor G) \wedge (\lnot S \lor (\lnot G)) $

One of Steve or George is happy and other is sad

$2. [S \lor (G \wedge (\lnot S)] \lor (\lnot G)$

George is happy when Steve is sad or George is sad

$3. S \lor [G \wedge (\lnot S \lor \lnot G) ]$

Steve is sad when George is happy or Steve is happy

Can anyone cross verify my solutions.Thank you

Comment: Side-note: $\lnot$ happy doesn't imply sad. This doesn't matter but it might come in handy in other problems

Comment: @Sergio i know but just for sake of simplicity

Comment: Considering your first statements a general formula it's equal to $((A \wedge B) \lor C) \wedge ((A \wedge B) \lor D)$, you can verify your answer by setting $\lnot S=C$ and $\lnot G=D$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we define that not happy if and only if sad, we have **$1.$ traslated correctly**. But there are some ambiguity for the second one, for example

> (George is happy when Steve is sad) or George is sad **$($Correct translation for $2.)$**

$$(\neg S\to G) \lor \neg G\tag{1}$$

> George is happy when (Steve is sad or George is sad)

$$(\neg S\lor\neg G)\to G\tag{2}$$

The second expression $[S∨(G∧(¬S)]∨(¬G)$ is actually equivalent to $(1)$ which says "(George is happy when Steve is sad) or George is sad", but not $(2)$. Consider a counter example $G=S=0$, that $$(¬S→G)∨¬G=(¬S∨¬G)→G$$
$$(¬0→0)∨¬0=(¬0∨¬0)→0$$
$$0∨1=1→0$$
$$1=0$$
This proves they are not the same when George and Steve are both sad.

Similarly for the third one

> (Steve is sad when George is happy) or Steve is happy

$$(G\to S)\lor S\tag{3}$$

> Steve is sad when (George is happy or Steve is happy)

$$(G\lor S)\to S\tag{4}$$
However, interestingly this time $(3)$ and $(4)$ are equivalent since
\begin{align}
(G\to S)\lor S\equiv&\neg G\lor S\lor S\\
\equiv&\neg G\lor S\\
\equiv&\neg G\lor S\land \top\\
\equiv&(\neg G\lor S)\land(\neg S\lor S)\\
\equiv&(\neg G\land\neg S)\lor S\\
\equiv&(G\lor S)\to S
\end{align}
And the expression $(S∨(G∧(¬S∨¬G)))$ is equivalent to $\neg S\to G$ which says that

> George is happy when Steve is sad. **$($Correct translation for $3.)$**

Comment: OK. The third part of the Q is Steve is happy or (Steve is sad and George is happy). How is this equivalent to last line of the answer

Comment: Is it because that when S is true then G can or cannot be true, so we have picked  (S and G) as answer ?

Comment: @JessicaGriffin to see why 'Steve is happy or (Steve is sad and George is happy)' $(S\lor(\neg S\land G))$ is equivalent to 'George is happy when Steve is sad' ($¬S→G$), here is a short proof
\begin{align}
(S\lor(\neg S\land G))\equiv&(S\lor\neg S)\land (S\lor G)\\
\equiv&\top\land(S\lor G)\\
\equiv&S\lor G\\
\equiv&\neg S\to G
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks...................

Answer (score 0):

## 1

Your answer is correct.

## 2

\begin{align} [∨(∧¬)]∨¬       & \equiv  [(∨)∧(∨¬)]∨¬ \\       & \equiv [(∨)∧\top]∨¬ \\        & \equiv (∨)∨¬ \\            & \equiv ∨(∨¬) \\          & \equiv ∨\top \\            & \equiv \top       \end{align}

Therefore, the proposition is a tautology, and

> Steve and George can have any mood.

## 3

\begin{align}
S∨[G∧(¬S∨¬G)] & \equiv S∨[(G∧¬S)∨(G∧¬G))] \\
&\equiv S∨[(G∧¬S)∨\bot)] \\
&\equiv S∨(G∧¬S) \\
&\equiv (S∨G)∧(S∨¬S) \\
&\equiv (S∨G)∧(S∨¬S) \\
&\equiv (S∨G)∧\top \\
&\equiv S∨G \\
&\end{align}

> Either Steve or George is happy, could be both.